# (#100) conflicting og:type found in path (nnn:game) and 'properties' (\"nnn:game\")", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the following error when trying to test my Story in the Graph API Explorer.
(#100) conflicting og:type found in path (nnn:game) and 'properties' (\"nnn:game\")",      "type": "OAuthException",      "code": 100

Note: `nnn` is just a place holder for the actual name and is not really being used.

I created an object called game.

Any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Anyone else have any suggestions? This seems like it should be really simple...

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have double quotes around the type you have given in your object …?

Comment: This is what it looks like. It was auto generated:
{"app_id":0000000000000,"type":"\"xxx:game\"","url":"\"http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/610919328950845\"","title":"\"Sample Game\"","image":"\"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/images\/devsite\/attachment_blank.png\"","description":"\"\""}

Comment: That looks like JSON – where and how are you using this exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to test it in the Graph API Explorer in FB but it always returns the error I mentioned above

Comment: And where was this auto-generated? Looks like the double quotes around the values are just wrong …

Comment: From within FB. When I click the GetCode option under Open Graph, Types

Comment: Looks like the code they are generating is just wrong – it should not have the double quotes escaped.

Comment: Same problem. why the hell "Facebook Developers" is so full of bugs??

Comment: @jbassking and  Here also same issue any solution is there...