# (#100) conflicting og:type found in path (xxxx:dish) and 'properties' (\“xxxx:dish\”)“, ”type“: ”OAuthException“, ”code": 100

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new developer for Facebook graph api. Now I get the error as the title, and find the same issue: [(#100) conflicting og:type found in path (nnn:game) and 'properties' (\"nnn:game\")", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351737/100-conflicting-ogtype-found-in-path-xxxgame-and-properties-xxxgame), but couldn't get the answer. Anyone have the suggestions?

This is what it looks like. It was auto generated by the GetCode option under Open Graph:

{"app_id":1234567890123456,"type":"\"xxxx:dish\"","url":"\"http://samples.ogp.me/1424325767819455\"","title":"\"Sample Dish\"","image":"\"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png\"","description":"\"\""}